# Add WildFly to IntelliJ Community

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss, ide, wildfly

I'm trying to add wildfly to the configuration servers but I can't find the option Application Server under Build, Exec..., All the tutorial showed me to go there and I don't know what to do now, any help?

[image: intellij]

Tried to see if there are any other video but nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IntelliJ Community Edition is not suitable for application server management. You need  the Ultimate Edition instead. See the [IntelliJ Edition comparison page](https://www.jetbrains.com/products/compare/?product=idea&product=idea-ce) under section "Deployment".

If you don't want to pay for the Ultimate Edition you can use Eclipse or Netbeans with application server integration for free.